# Modify CMakeLists.txt for googletests in order to use googlemock

Tags: cmake, googletest

I was checking the [quickstarter](http://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html) to use googletest with cmake. I was wondering how I should modify the CMakeLists.txt they provide (given below) in order to use googlemock.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  hello_test.cc
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  GTest::gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

for the moment, `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` works but `#include <gmock/gmock.h>` doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMock should be available via `GTest::gmock` cmake target. At least this is the target name used in the cmake configuration files of a GTest build installed via cmake.

```
target_link_libraries(
    hello_test
    GTest::gmock
)
```